# apex:outputLink target="_blank" from VF in Lightning now opens records in a Classic view

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, urlfor

I'm seeing some previously unseen behaviour changes in Lightning Experience, Summer 2017. I have a VisualForce page embedded as a tab of a Lightning record page. About two months ago I added some record links intended to open in new windows. Originally these opened in new windows and rendered in Lightning. Now they render in Classic instead, without a header.

Examples:

```
<apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="{!URLFOR($Action.Booking__c.View, bw.b.id)}">
  [open]
</apex:outputLink>
<apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!bw.b.id}">
  [open]
</apex:outputLink>
```

The above links both open a classic view of the record. In particular, the generated link always includes the parameter `isdtp=p1`.

In contrast:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/{!bw.b.id}">[open]</a>
```

The above opens it in a new window and renders the record in Lightning.

Anyone know if there's a way I can force that `apex:outputLink`, if in Lightning, to render the new window in Lightning?

I wonder if this is related to the following Known Issue that was fixed earlier in this release:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jOxQAI
As it entailed a broken behaviour of URLFOR that had to be fixed... and maybe this was an unintended side effect?